# Print all subarrays of a given array

Tags: python, list

Given an array write an algorithm to print all the possible sub arrays. The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. Then T test cases follow. Each test case contains an integer N denoting the size of the array A. Then in the next lines are N space separated values representing the array A. Print each sub-array element on a new-line.

```
t = int(input())
for z in range(t):
    n = int(input()) 
    a = list(map(int, input().split()))  

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i,n+1):
            for k in range(i,j):
                print(a[k], end=" ")
            print()
```

Sample Input

```
1
3
1 2 3
```

Sample Output

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
2 
2 3 
3
```

I've tried everything best I can do.

Comment: What is wrong? This seems to work fine

Comment: @RobertCotterman I tested the code and this seems to work (maybe some empty lines to remove)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your issue is that you have empty lines, simplify your code to directly slice the list will all needed items.

You can use unpacking in `print` to have space separated elements by default.

```
t = int(input())
for z in range(t):
    n = int(input()) 
    a = list(map(int, input().split()))  

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1,n+1):
            print(*a[i:j])
```

input/ouput:

```
1
3
1 2 3  # end of input
1
1 2
1 2 3
2
2 3
3
```

Comment: what * will do here? @mozway

Comment: @Shivanandam this is to expand the iterable `a`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of what you have done, you can go through a simple and general way like this:

```
a = input().split()

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if j>=i:
            print(*a[i:j+1])
```

Output:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
2
2 3
3
```

Answer (score 0):

(try this) You can get and print all subsets of an array by the next:

In array A at every step, we have two choices for each element either we can ignore the element or we can include the element in our subset.

`function`

```py
def subsetsUtil(A, subset, index):
    print(*subset)
    for i in range(index, len(A)): 
        
        # include the A[i] in subset. 
        subset.append(A[i])
        
        # move onto the next element. 
        subsetsUtil(A, subset, i + 1) 
        
        # exclude the A[i] from subset and 
        # triggers backtracking.
        subset.pop(-1) 
    return
```

#### below function returns the subsets of vector A.

```py
def subsets(A):
    global res
    subset = []
    
    # keeps track of current element in vector A 
    index = 0
    subsetsUtil(A, subset, index)
```

#### Implement the array and call the function

```py
array = [1, 2, 3]
subsets(array)
```

-> res will store all subsets.

#### Time complexity

`O(2 ^ (number of elements inside array))`

--> because at every step we have two choices either include or ignore.

Comment: Please don't just copy and paste from [another site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-to-find-all-subsets/) without attribution or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
t = int(input())
for z in range(t):
    n = int(input()) 
    a = []
    for y in range(n):
        x = int(input())
        a.append(x) 

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i,n+1):
            for k in range(i,j):
                print(a[k], end=" ")
            print()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The code is another version of the answer given with basic syntax

```
for i in range(int(input())):#no of testcases eg:1
  n=int(input())#no of input eg:3
  x=list(map(int,input().split()))#values in the input eg:1 2 3
  l=[]
  for j in range(n):
    for k in range(j,n):
      l.append(x[k])
      print(*l)
    l=[]
```

Output:

```
1
3
1 2 3
1
1 2
1 2 3
2
2 3
3
```

Comment: How does this answer the question ?